# Redirecting to a local file throws an error (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I'm in the process of developing a Chrome Extension, and I've encountered a problem related to redirecting to a local file in Manifest v3. Despite my attempts, I've been unable to find a solution.

Interestingly, when I redirect to an existing URL instead of a local file, it seems to work flawlessly. I experimented with redirecting to a URL using `chrome.runtime.getURL`, but unfortunately, that approach also yielded no results. The issue doesn't seem to be stemming from the `updateDynamicRules` either. I attempted to set the rules within the ruleset file, but this approach proved unsuccessful as well.

The code throws the following error: `GET https://d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/js/app-8d620ab3.js net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT`

service-worker.js:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        removeRuleIds: [1, 2],
        addRules: [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "priority": 1,
                "action": {
                  "type": "redirect",
                  "redirect": { "extensionPath": "/scripts/app-8d620ab3.js" }
                },
                "condition": {
                  "urlFilter": "https://d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/js/app-8d620ab3.js",
                  "resourceTypes": ["script"]
                }
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "priority": 1,
                "action": {
                  "type": "redirect",
                  "redirect": { "extensionPath": "/scripts/806-b665410e.js" }
                },
                "condition": {
                  "urlFilter": "https://d35aaqx5ub95lt.cloudfront.net/js/806-b665410e.js",
                  "resourceTypes": ["script"]   
                }
            }
        ]
    })
```

Your assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "/scripts/806-b665410e.js" should be added to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Comment: I did add them to the Web Accessible Resources, but sadly that didn't help as well.

Comment: Assuming the declaration is correct and you've reloaded the extension afterwards, it's a bug in Chrome, which you can report in https://crbug.com. As a workaround, try using `txt` instead of `js` file extension.

Comment: That didn't help either. I've tried every possible combination I could think of, and none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't much of a solution, but I simply uploaded the files to a file-uploading website and it worked flawlessly.